# PostgreSQL: Exclude null value from comparison across columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case, boolean-logic

Imagine this table:

```
id   col1    col2    col3    col4
1    A       A       C
2            B       B       B
3    D               D
```

I would like to add a column that tells me if all not-null values of the row match.

So the ideal output is:

```
id   col1    col2    col3    col4   is_a_match
1    A       A       C              FALSE
2            B       B       B      TRUE
3    D               D              TRUE
```

I have tried:

```
select *,
     case  
         when col1 = col2
                and col2 = col3
                and col3 = col4
         then 'TRUE'
         else 'FALSE'
     end as is_a_match
from my_table
```

But would return `false` for all due to the null values.

What is the best way to achieve the output above?

Comment: What's the desired result if all but one columns are NULL, or all columns are NULL? Is the question about exactly 4 value columns or an arbitrary number of columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could transform the columns to rows, the count the distinct values. That will automatically ignore NULL values:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct x.col)
        from (
          values (t.col1), 
                 (t.col2), 
                 (t.col3), 
                 (t.col4)
        ) as x(col)
        where x.col is not null) = 1 as is_a_match
from the_table t
```

If you don't want to list all columns manually, you can use some JSON magic to turn the columns to rows in order to count the distinct values:

```
select t.*, 
       (select count(distinct x.val)
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t) - 'id') as x(col, val)
        where x.val is not null) = 1
from the_table t
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple boolean logic - looks a bit awkward, but I bet it's the fastest way:

```sql
SELECT *
     , COALESCE(NOT (col1 <> col2 OR col1 <> col3 OR col1 <> col4
                  OR col2 <> col3 OR col2 <> col4
                  OR col3 <> col4), true) AS is_a_match
FROM   tbl;
```

Any non-null, non-equal pair makes the core expression `true`. Invert with `NOT`, default to true with `COALESCE`.

Or closer to your original attempt, which wasn't far off:

```sql
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN (col1 <> col2 OR col1 <> col3 OR col1 <> col4
               OR col2 <> col3 OR col2 <> col4
               OR col3 <> col4)
            THEN false
            ELSE true END is_a_match
FROM   tbl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=083bfccbd2beaea23342c974b409ad7c)*

Either way, the point is to invert the logic: To ignore comparison to NULL values, look for **mismatches** (which is only `true` for two not-null values), not for matches.

The code bloats with more columns. But for a hand full of columns, walking through all pairs is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns is variable, flipping into and out of jsonb could save you some cutting and pasting:

```
with pivots as (
  select d.id, c.k, c.v
    from de_data d
         cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d)) as c(k,v)
   where c.k != 'id'
     and c.v is not null
), match_check as (
  select id, count(distinct v) = 1 as is_a_match 
    from pivots 
   group by id
)
select d.*, mc.is_a_match
  from de_data d
       left join match_check mc on mc.id = d.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=500b2e611956af0e82ac47179da5023a)*